# Unmet dependencies when trying to run Alexa Voice Service on my Rasberry Pi b+

Tags: raspberry-pi3, raspbian, alexa-skills-kit

The code should com back as configuration complete, but it keeps getting stuck with this.

I already made several upgrades and everything seems to be fine.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo bash setup.sh config.json [-s 1234]
    ################################################################################
    ################################################################################


    AVS Device SDK Raspberry pi Script - Terms and Agreements


    The AVS Device SDK is dependent on several third-party libraries, environments, 
    and/or other software packages that are installed using this script from 
    third-party sources ("External Dependencies"). These are terms and conditions 
    associated with the External Dependencies 
    (available at https://github.com/alexa/avs-device-sdk/wiki/Dependencies) that 
    you need to agree to abide by if you choose to install the External Dependencies.


    If you do not agree with every term and condition associated with the External 
    Dependencies, enter "QUIT" in the command line when prompted by the installer.
    Else enter "AGREE".


    ################################################################################
    ################################################################################
    agree
    ################################################################################
    Proceeding with installation
    ################################################################################
    ==============> INSTALLING REQUIRED TOOLS AND PACKAGE ============

    Hit:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease
    Hit:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease
    Reading package lists... Done
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    build-essential is already the newest version (12.6).
    gcc is already the newest version (4:8.3.0-1+rpi2).
    gcc set to manually installed.
    git is already the newest version (1:2.20.1-2).
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-good is already the newest version (1.14.4-1).
    libssl1.0-dev is already the newest version (1.0.2q-2).
    python3-pip is already the newest version (18.1-5+rpt1).
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:

    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libcurl4-openssl-dev : Conflicts: libssl1.0-dev but 1.0.2q-2 is to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Anything helps I havent been able to find anything online

Answer (score 0):

If you're building the SDK on Debian 10.0 "buster" you can just remove the **libssl1.0-dev** package from the list on pi.sh (apt-get command on line #34).

From Debian's [packages site](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libssl1.0-dev): "This is a transition package that will go away after the stretch release to provide the 1.0.X APIs for those packages that are not ready for the 1.1 version yet."

Then you can build the client without any issues.